# create sql server role for stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a mvc 4 web application that interacts with a sql server database over a number of environments.

The user I connect to the database with is different in each environment. I generate a generic script of my stored procedures during each build and deployment and run it in to each environment. In the script I grant execute permissions to the db user on each sproc.

At the moment I needed a script for each environment as the user is different in each - which is a pain!

Would it be possible to create a role in each environment, same name in each environment and grant execute permissions to the role as oppose to the user? The user would be set up as part of that role.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is exactly what database roles are for, you create a custom database role, apply the permissions to that and then you simply add the user to that database role.

Have a look at the link below for details on how to accomplish this:

[SQL Server - Custom Database Role](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/88/posts/10181/sql-server-custom-database-role.aspx)